# how i Fetch text from files on server?

Tags: c#, office-interop

have web application for cv  uploading i want to fetch text during uploading 
i have only 2 types of CVs (Word & PDF )
i am using **ITextsharp**  && `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and it works fine but On server not working

```
 string Mainer(string pathfile)
        {


        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        string totaltext = "";
        try
        {

            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            // object truee = True;
            object oTrue = false;
            object path = pathfile;
            object readOnly = true;
            object pass = "";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, pass, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref oTrue, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                totaltext += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
            }

            docs.Close();

            word.Quit();

            word = null;
            docs = null;
            GC.Collect();
            return totaltext;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            //((_Document)word).Close();
            //((_Application)word).Quit();
            word.Quit();

            word = null;

            //ererorcount = ererorcount + 1;
            //listerrors.Add(pathfile);

            return totaltext;

            //   return ererorcount.ToString();
        }


    }
```

Error Is

> Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: Are you giving physical path in pathfile?

Comment: i am sure that path and permission is ok and File Is Exist too @LitisqeKumar

Comment: Ditch interop and use the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx). Interop works only if you have Word installed. That's what the word means - interoperability *with* Word, the application. It's a *very* bad idea to use this in a server environment though, as you end up starting one Word instance per request. With the SDK you can open or create Word files without installing Word

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

You may consider using the Open XML SDK or any other third party componets designed for the server-side execution. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.